# Qualcomm Atheros wifi not working in Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS in LENOVO B40-80

Tags: 14.04, lenovo

I have Lenovo B40-80 with default Windows 8.1 installed. I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 but WIFI is not working.

I have also executed the wireless info script from this [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11820650/). Output of this script is present on this [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11820389/).

Comment: You have an adapter that is supposed to be supported by `ath10k` kernel driver. It is new and not all devices are listed there. And also you will need to find and extract firmware from a Windows driver. I do not have a complete solution yet.

Comment: You are probably running kernel 4.3 or a later version of kernel 4.2, this is a bug as listed here - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1257500